What is the alternative to condition number as a cost function for a NLP
My problem description.
I have robot manipulator dynamics with $n$ degree of freedoms:
$$
\tau = \xi(q, \dot{q}, \ddot{q}) \cdot \chi,
$$
where $\tau, q, \dot{q}, \ddot{q} \in \mathbb{R}^n $ are vectors of torques, and generalized coordinates, velocities and accelerations of the robot, $\chi$ is a vector of parameters (mass, inertia and etc.).
I want to solve parameters identification problem: $\chi = \xi(q, \dot{q}, \ddot{q})^+ \cdot \tau$, but it is necessary to make $\xi(q, \dot{q}, \ddot{q})$ matrix well-conditioned.
What I did.
I have an optimization problem where I need to minimize the condition number of the observation matrix
$$ \mathbf{\Xi}(q, \dot{q}, \ddot{q}, t) = \big[ \xi\big(q(t_1), \dot{q}(t_1), \ddot{q}(t_1)\big),\: \xi\big(q(t_2), \dot{q}(t_2), \ddot{q}(t_2)\big), \:\dots,\:\xi\big(q(t_m), \dot{q}(t_m), \ddot{q}(t_m)\big) \big]^T, 
$$
$t \in \mathbb{R}$. This matrix is constructed by vertically stacking the regressor $ \xi\big(q(t_i), \dot{q}(t_i), \ddot{q}(t_i)\big) $.
The trajectory is computed as a partial sum of a Fourier series in regression form:
$$
[q(t), \dot{q}(t), \ddot{q}(t)]^T = \mathbf{\omega}(t) \cdot \mathbf{\theta}^T
$$
where $ \mathbf{\omega}(t) $ represents nonlinear trigonometric functions of the Fourier series, and $ \mathbf{\theta} $ are the Fourier coefficients $ a, b $ in matrix form.
Objective:
$$ \min \: \mathbf{\Xi}(\theta) $$
s.t:

Joint limits: $ q_l \leq q(t) \leq q_u $
Velocity limits: $ ||\dot{q}(t)|| \leq \dot{q}_{\text{limit}} $
Acceleration limits: $||\ddot{q}(t)|| \leq \ddot{q}_{\text{limit}} $
The robot's end-effector must remain above the ground at all times: $ z_{tool} \geq z_{\text{limit}}$, $z_{tool}$ is z-coordinate of robot's tool.
The end-effector must not pass through a virtual cylinder around the robot (e.g., for a robot in a "candle" position, the cylinder has a small radius around the robot's body): $ x_{tool}^2 + y_{tool}^2 \geq r^2$
Initial conditions: The velocities and accelerations at the initial time ( t=0 ) should be zero: $\dot{q(0)} = 0, \ddot{q(0)} = 0$.

My question is
I did try:

scipy.optimization.minimize with methods "trust-constr" and "SLSQP" but it didn't work with constraints on radius.
casADi, with method "ipopt", but there is no computation of condition number in symbolic way.

Could anyone recommend relevant methods for solving this type of optimization problem? May be there are another ways to setup Objective?
Thank you!
